# NZ PR rejected, will it affect Australian Student Visa subclass 500?

Tags: australia, student-visa, students, new-zealand, pr

My father had applied for New Zealand PR for himself and the family last year but unfortunately, the PR application was rejected due to insufficient points.

I got accepted into The University of Sydney and I'm applying for an Australian student visa (subclass 500) to enroll in my course. However, there is a question that I have to answer in order to submit my application.

The question is: "Have you, or any person included in this application, ever had an application for entry or further stay in Australia or any other country refused, or had a visa canceled? If Yes, please provide details below."

Do you think I should mention my dad's NZ visa refusal because I was also a part of his visa application?

Answer (score 2):

I think the wisest move would be to say YES, and in the notes explain the details of the situation. Let them decide whether your father's failed application for PR (on which you were included) is relevant.

The reason why I suggest this is that if they later discovered that you were included in a failed application for PR and had not told them about it, it might look worse.